# PIN-locked Samsung A41 with dead screen - photo recovery

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, broken-screen

A friend gave me their Samsung A41 to see if I could recover some photos from it for them. They dropped it and the screen just doesn't work anymore. The phone seems OK but when connected to my Windows 10 PC it just shows up in File Explorer as "Fred's A41" and I can't browse the storage. I know the PIN code for the phone and tried to submit that using adb shell commands but all I get returned is "error: closed". **The owner didn't use a Samsung or Google account on it and debugging mode is NOT enabled.**

I've tried getting the phone display on to a monitor and also my TV using two different USB-C to HDMI hubs (with mouse & keyboard attached) and umpteen different HDMI cables but both monitor and TV just state that they can't pick up an HDMI signal. I then heard that this model doesn't support this method *sigh*.

I've also tried various bits of trial software which claim to do what I want to do but they either don't cover this model, presume that debugging mode is already enabled or instruct me to enable it on the phone. If I could see the display to do that then I wouldn't need their software!! Software that claims to remove PIN locks seems to do it by nuking the phone and reinstalling Android i.e. losing the files I'm after in the process....unless someone knows differently?

The photos are of sentimental value and I'm trying my best but I work in IT Systems Admin - not phone hacking - but anything vaguely technical seems to head my way.

Can anyone offer any suggestions for things to try before I just take a hammer to this brick?

Thanks

Comment: Use a simple USB keyboard connected to the phone and enter the PIN blind. It often works with RETURN+ PIN + RETURN. Then remove the keyboard and reconnect the PC. If you are lucky you can then browse the files from the PC.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm trying that via a USC-C hub but haven't been lucky thus far. I'm not familiar with Samsung phones so I don't know how it behaves when it's asleep and it gets connected to a hub i.e. do messages appear on-screen that need to be dealt with in order to get to the PIN screen? I'll keep trying though.

Comment: What price is sentiment ?  Maybe just get the display/screen replaced.  Or take it one of the repair shops and they may be able to recover them.

Comment: Do not use a HUB, just connect the keyboard directly to the phone. best are keyboards without any special features (no integrated hub, illumination, smartcard readers, sd card readers, ...) as it increases the power consumption or requires a built-in USB hub.

Comment: Speaking to another Samsung user, they tell me that they need to swipe up in order to get to the PIN screen. Any idea what the keyboard equivalent of that is when the phone is connected to an adaptor/hub? Enter? Esc? Space?

Comment: On the devices I have seen pressing RETURN/ENTER has the same effect as swiping up. Not sure about Samsung (don't have a Samsung phone at the moment).

Comment: Anyone with any further ideas? Or is this something that simply cannot be done?